# Electromagnetic inertial reaction force?

Tags: electromagnetism, virtual-particles, inertia, lienard-wiechert

I accelerate charged particle $A$ causing virtual photons to travel to distant charged particle $B$ which feels an electromagnetic force proportional to $A$'s acceleration (for a classical field description of this effect see [Feynman Lectures vol 1 ch. 28](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_28.html) Eqn 28.6).

Virtual photons conserve momentum and energy between the two charged particles.

Is there an inertia-like reaction force back at particle $A$ due to its electromagnetic interaction with particle $B$?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Abraham-Lorentz force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force)

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious answer is yes, of course. How could it be otherwise? Momentum is conserved.

But it depends on how you divide up the world. Charged particle A is getting accelerated by something. That doesn't just happen for no reason. Charged particle B interacts both with charged particle A and also with whatever is accelerating A. It's the whole system that conserves momentum, not just A and B.

A and B may not conserve momentum when you just consider them alone, and ignore whatever is accelerating A.

Comment: I put charged particle $A$ inside a heavy charged hollow insulator along with some apparatus that produces an EM field local to particle $A$. Will particle $A$ move as though its inertia has been altered due to its interaction with the charged insulator?